# Does Facebook iOS app need to be approved by Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook

my iOS app uses the Facebook SDK and users can interact with my iOS app via Facebook. EX. Send friends scores, invites etc etc

I made a new app within the Facebook Developer page, hooked everything up and it works just fine. I turned off sandbox mode within Facebook and I submitted my app the other day to Apple. Today, I noticed there is also a submit app for Facebook.

Am I required to have Facebook approve my iOS app in order to use Facebook services in my iOS app or is this only if I want my iOS app to show up in Facebook App Center?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit an app using Facebook services, even the integrated Facebook system account you don't need to do anything special, only apple has to approve your app, off course Facebook has their rules, and if you don't respect them, they can decide to turn off some services that your app doesn't respect

Comment: thank you! So what is the benefit of submitting the "Facebook app"? More users can find it because it will be in the Facebook App Store?

Answer (score 5):

When you registered your app to facebook. 
Facebook provide only **three** permisson , these permission is by default approved

1. **email**
   Provides access to the person's primary email address. This permission is approved by default.
2. **public_profile**
   Provides access to a person's basic information, including first name, last name, profile picture, gender and age range. This permission is approved by default.
3. **user_friends**
   Provides access to a person's list of friends that also use your app. This permission is approved by default.

If you want to use more feature apart from them , then you need to submit your app to facebook for use other feature

like if want to get user photo then you have to submit your app for get **user_photo** permission 
facebook check that how you are using user_photo in your app
And you also need to upload screen shot with submission that show you are using facebook photo